# JavaScript Popup Window - Restrict resize arrows

Tags: javascript

I've created a JavaScript popup window, that pops up perfectly and as how I would like it to be. But the customer I've built it for does not want the window to be resized as in the drag resize. This also made me want to prevent the maximize and minimize buttons from appearing within the window also, Only if possible. I'm not too bothered if you cant do that. I'm more concerned with the user resize.

My code is :

```
<!-- Pop Up Script -->
<script language="javascript">
 function popUp(URL) {
  day = new Date();
  id = day.getTime();
  eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=1600,height=900'      );");
  }
 </script>
```

Many Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean by user resize?

Comment: Basically where you can resize the window yourself using the arrows in the each corner of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Firefox 3+: [Mozilla's window.open notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open).

`resizable`: **Starting with Firefox 3, secondary windows are always resizable**

If you're going to be 'in charge' of the content of the opened window, you could try a [nasty hack](http://www.irt.org/script/1626.htm). It is a body-onresize listener that snaps the window back to whatever size you want whenever a user foolishly attempts to resize your perfectly proportioned window.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing worse than a popup window is a popup window that thwarts my attempts to resize it.

Comment: Very useful answer, Thanks! Seems though most users are going to be FireFox 3+ I'm just going to tell the customer "No Can Do" :) Many Thanks!